# OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ Check TJR Options

Tags: soap, soapui, sabre

My steps:

1. SessionCreateRQ -- success
2. TravelItineraryAddInfoLLSRQ --success
3. OTA_AirBookLLSRQ - success
4. OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ - failed

I got error message `UNABLE - CHECK TJR OPTION FOR PQR OR PQPLUS ACTIVE` from OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ

I don't see any documentation about this error message.
did i missed something?

Comment: I'm hoping you've been able to overcome this issue at this time, but - if not - we can certainly enable the required setting/s for OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ to work for you.

What is your IPCC? And, can you share the sample request that is returning the error?

Answer (score 2):

A new TJR indicator has been created to control access to enhanced PQ by agency.

Maybe you are trying to use this new capabilities of OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ.

The TJR indicator PQPLUS allows you to access the new enhanced PQ functions. Once you have turned on the PQPLUS indicator, you are no longer permitted to create, modify or issue tickets from a Phase IV and you have access to all the new PQ functions.

You must activate the Price Quote Record function in your agency’s Travel Journal Record (TJR) security feature. Changes to the TJR require the keyword SUBMGR and duty code 9 in your Employee Profile Record (EPR)

This is the entry:
W/PQPLUS‡ON